# Angular not working on Safari browser, but working well on other browsers

Tags: angular

Angular 5 Project working on Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox etc.
But only not working on Safari Browser.

I am getting error

> Can't find variable: DragEvent

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should consider upgrading your project to latest Angular. https://update.angular.io/

Comment: What errors do you see in Browser console?

Comment: I attached error with screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had same issue, just search for `DragEvent` and change them `any`

Comment: I can't find `DragEvent`

Comment: Sure, give me a few mins

Comment: For anyone here whose first reaction is, "but DragEvent is a type, how the heck does it land in the browser?!", the TypeScript compiler appears to generate metadata stuff making DragEvent becoming a variable. Search (Ctrl+Shift+F) for DragEvent in the Chrome Dev Tools, and you'll see where it appears.

Answer (score 0):

DragEvent is not supported in Safari. In your code change 'DragEvent' to any.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/DragEvent

Comment: Example, if you had this :
 ```  
// Change this -> public onDrop(event: DragEvent) {  
// to this-> public onDrop(event: any) {. 
```

Comment: OK...so if the object is undefined, the type is irrelevant. You need a polyfill.